# SQLx long query results in Io(Kind(ConnectionAborted))

Tags: sql, sql-server, rust, rust-sqlx

So I have a big and complex query I run once a month, and I've just tried to rewrite the entire thing in Rust/SQLx. However I keep getting `Io(Kind(ConnectionAborted))` when I run my big query.

```
let conn_options = MssqlConnectOptions::new()
    .database("")
    .username("")
    .password("")
    .host("")
    .port();

let pool = MssqlPoolOptions::new()
    .max_lifetime(Duration::from_secs(12000))
    .idle_timeout(Duration::from_secs(12000))
    .connect_with(conn_options)
    .await?;
```

This is how I do my connection, I even added `max_lifetime` and `idle_timeout` but it did not solve my problem.

```
let result = query("")
    .fetch_all(pool)
    .await?;
```

I am using SQLx `0.6.3`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: SQLx completely removed MSSQL support from their driver "pending a full rewrite". You probably want to have a read through [Update: Our Plans Regarding MSSQL and Other Proprietary Drivers #1616](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/discussions/1616) to understand not only the shortcomings of the old driver code but also some of the AGPL issues.